# Rails 3 model logger

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, logging

I have a model, but I don't want it to write to the common log its queries. Is it possible to switch logger for some model?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233401/custom-logger-in-rails-3

Comment: that is logger for full application. and I want to have some separate logger for a model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

Create a custom Logger if you want to format it differently.You can ignore this if format needs to be the same.

```
class ModelLogger < Logger
  def format_message(severity, timestamp, progname, msg)
    "#{timestamp.to_formatted_s:)db)} #{severity} #{msg}\n"
  end
end
```

In the config/initializers/ , create logs.rb and add this:

```
model_logfile = File.open("#{RAILS_ROOT}/log/model.log", 'a')
model_logfile.sync = true
MODEL_LOG = ModelLogger.new(model_logfile)
```

Now, after you restart your server,

```
MODEL_LOG.debug "This will be logged to model.log"
MODEL_LOG.error "Errors also can be logged."
```

Comment: I know that. But the model writes its sql queries to the log and I want ignore some of them

Answer (score 1):

This should answer your question. Replace STDOUT with whatever meets your needs
[how to change the rails logger to use standard out from rake tasks (rails2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800032/how-to-change-the-rails-logger-to-use-standard-out-from-rake-tasks-rails2)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using push-core gem and it writes many annoying messages to the log, such following, every 2 seconds:

```
Push::Message Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "push_messages".* FROM "push_messages" ...
```

I've added following code into an initializer in order to remove "Push::Message Load" events from the log:

```
# Disable annoying (every 2 sec) "Push::Message Load" events
ActiveRecord::LogSubscriber.class_eval do
  alias_method :old_sql, :sql

  def sql(event)
    return if event.payload[:name] =~ /Push::Message Load/
    old_sql(event)
  end
end
```